# Create multiple elements in QML XmlListModel

Tags: javascript, xml, qml, vlc

I am trying to get xml data into a QML XmlListModel, I've gotten most of it working now but bit lost with the last part to get multiple category streams.

The xml itself looks like this:

```
<root>
<fullscreen>false</fullscreen>
<aspectratio>default</aspectratio>
<audiodelay>0</audiodelay>
<apiversion>3</apiversion>
<currentplid>4</currentplid>
<time>1</time>
<volume>0</volume>
<length>9907</length>
<random>false</random>
<rate>1</rate>
<state>paused</state>
<loop>false</loop>
<version>2.1.5 Rincewind</version>
<position>0.00018763827392831</position>
<repeat>false</repeat>
<subtitledelay>0</subtitledelay>
    <category name="meta">
        <info name="title">
            The Movie
        </info> 
        <info name="filename">
            The Movie
        </info> 
        </category>
    <category name="Stream 0">
        <info name="Type">Video</info> 
        <info name="Frame rate">23.976215</info> 
        <info name="Decoded format">Planar 4:2:0 YUV</info> 
        <info name="Codec">H264 - MPEG-4 AVC (part 10) (avc1)</info> 
        <info name="Language">English</info> 
        <info name="Resolution">1024x542</info> 
    </category>
        <category name="Stream 1">
        <info name="Bitrate">384 kb/s</info> 
        <info name="Type">Audio</info> 
        <info name="Channels">3F2R/LFE</info> 
        <info name="Sample rate">48000 Hz</info> 
        <info name="Language">Russian</info> 
        <info name="Codec">A52 Audio (aka AC3) (a52 )</info> 
    </category><category name="Stream 6"><info name="Description">Full</info> 
        <info name="Type">Subtitle</info> 
        <info name="Language">English</info> 
        <info name="Codec">Text subtitles with various tags (subt)</info> 
        </category><category name="Stream 3"><info name="Description">Forced</info> 
        <info name="Type">Subtitle</info> 
        <info name="Language">Russian</info> 
        <info name="Codec">Text subtitles with various tags (subt)</info> 
    </category>
        <category name="Stream 7">
        <info name="Description">SDH</info> 
        <info name="Type">Subtitle</info> 
        <info name="Language">English</info> 
        <info name="Codec">Text subtitles with various tags (subt)</info> 
    </category><category name="Stream 5"><info name="Description">Forced</info> 
        <info name="Type">Subtitle</info> 
        <info name="Language">English</info> 
        <info name="Codec">Text subtitles with various tags (subt)</info> 
        </category>
    <category name="Stream 4">
        <info name="Description">Full</info> 
        <info name="Type">Subtitle</info> 
        <info name="Language">Russian</info> 
        <info name="Codec">Text subtitles with various tags (subt)</info> 
    </category>
        <category name="Stream 2">
        <info name="Codec">A52 Audio (aka AC3) (a52 )</info> 
        <info name="Type">Audio</info> 
        <info name="Language">English</info> 
        <info name="Sample rate">48000 Hz</info> 
    </category>  
    </information>
</root>
```

And for it I got this xmllistmodel working to get the data out:

```
 XmlListModel{
    id: xmlModel
    query: "/root"
    XmlRole{ name: "fullscreen"; query: "fullscreen/string()"}
    XmlRole{ name: "aspectratio"; query: "aspectratio/string()"}
    XmlRole{ name: "audiodelay"; query: "audiodelay/string()"}
    XmlRole{ name: "currentplid"; query: "currentplid/string()"}
    XmlRole{ name: "time"; query: "time/string()"}
    XmlRole{ name: "volume"; query: "volume/string()"}
    XmlRole{ name: "length"; query: "length/string()"}
    XmlRole{ name: "random"; query: "random/string()"}
    XmlRole{ name: "rate"; query: "rate/string()"}
    XmlRole{ name: "state"; query: "state/string()"}
    XmlRole{ name: "loop"; query: "loop/string()"}
    XmlRole{ name: "repeat"; query: "repeat/string()"}
    XmlRole{ name: "subtitledelay"; query: "subtitledelay/string()"}

    XmlRole{ name: "artist"; query: "information/category/info[@name='artist']/string()"}
    XmlRole{ name: "album"; query: "information/category/info[@name='album']/string()"}
    XmlRole{ name: "filename"; query: "information/category/info[@name='filename']/string()"}

    //Stream 0 is hard-coded :(
    XmlRole{ name: "type"; query: "information/category[@name='Stream 0']/info[@name='Type']/string()"}
}
```

All above information is fine but what I can't seem to get properly is the multiple stream information. As depending on the file there could only be 2 streams or even 10 if user has more audio tracks or subtitles. 
The last line in the xmllistmodel I can lookup the type of the stream 0 but then it needs to be hard-coded.
What I am trying to find is the stream number what type it is.

Is there any way to get this information from xml using qml for all of the streams?

Thanks :)